# How to use example dependent costs with SVM-light?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am working with SVM-light. I would like to use example dependent costs for training my model.

Although on the top page ([SVM-light](http://svmlight.joachims.org/)) it says "can train SVMs with cost models and example dependent costs ", I cannot figure out how.

Can someone explain how to use this feature of SVM-light or point me to any document that explains how to do this?

**EDIT**: I figured out that I can specify "cost" in my example file. So each line of my example file becomes something like:

< line > .=. < target > **cost:< value >** < feature >:< value > < feature >:< value > ... < feature >:< value > # < info >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I can specify "cost" in my example file. So each line of my example file becomes something like:

< line > .=. < target > cost:< value > < feature >:< value > < feature >:< value > ... < feature >:< value > # < info >

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by manipulating the training set. Specifically, if you want to weight some example **x** *n* times as much as other samples, simply include this example *n* times in the train set; mistakes on **x** will then be *n* times as costly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It works in some sense, but I also wanted to set the cost of a slack variable to 0.1, 0.5 or so. I figured out the way to do it and edited my question.